# Appium cannot find view elements with it's accessibilityId's

Tags: ios, appium, accessibility, identifier

I'm using Appium (Mobile App Automation for Testing) to test an iOS app.
Appium finds view on to test by accessibility identifier but when I run test with appium app (inspector) it only sees the view elements with image and it declare image names as accessibility elements though I set all view elements accessibility id's programmatically.

What can I do instead of findingViewByXpath?

Comment: what have you tried?
people are unlikely to answer question if they do not see you tried anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, you have to run your project on Simulator or on device after you set view elements accessibilityId's. Just build project is not enough to update changes on Appium side.